# Kubernetes Ingress routing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I would like to be able to reach main page located at /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html of my pod. I want to use URL http://myexternalclusterIP/web
Instead of redirecting to the main page my query tries to find the /web path inside the pod.
If I use DNS hostname, this all works fine, why doesn't it work with IP address?

My ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-my
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /web
        backend:
          service:
            name: newsite
            port:
              number: 1856
```

My svc config:

```
Name:              newsite
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=newsite
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=newsite
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.108.204.71
Port:              <unset>  1856/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.126:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Are you using any cloud environment and getting `externalIP` or you are using local environment with `MetalLB`? Did you use own nginx manifest or from [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#updating-the-deployment) with own selector? Are you using `Nginx Ingress`?

Comment: I'm not using externalIP or MetalLB or any Ingress controller. I have default k8s installation, exposed pod via ClusterIP and almost untouched default Ingress manifest from documentation you mentioned.

Comment: Did you configure firewall? It's kubeadm or minikube? How are you trying to reach your service, what command and from where?

Comment: All right, please ignore my inittial question. I have IP address from 'kubectl cluster-info'. Using nginx-ingress-controller I only can access endpoints via Load-Balance nginx-ingress-controller service IP. What if I want to use my address from 'kubectl cluster-info'? Do I have to use different Ingress controller instead?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? According to SO rule, each question should be separately created.